# How to determine number of records on a socrata table

Tags: socrata

Is there a way to determine how many records are available to download for a socarata table?

I'm using the API endpoint routines. I can down the file but it would be nice to know how many records are available to download before starting a download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, the most straightforward way would be to view the source dataset.

Example: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/Transportation-Network-Providers-Trips/m6dm-c72p

[Screen clip of "What's in this Dataset?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfLLT.png)

[Screen clip of more precise count from the bottom of the data preview grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCV6Y.png)

However, you can also do it through the API.

Example: https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/m6dm-c72p.json?$select=count(*)

```
[{"count":"100717116"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. The API approach is what I was looking for.